# When can you subtract two inequalities?

Tags: inequality

If you cannot always subtract two inequalities, e.g. you can not subtract (B) from (A) to form (C):

```
(A) 2x < y
(B)  x < z
(C)  x < y - z
```

Then, what are the situations that you can subtract two inequalities?

For example, if all variables on either side are positive, would this allow you to subtract the inequalities? Edit: This example is clearly false.

Are there any situations where it is safe to subtract inequalities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you cannot, not even if the values are all positive.  Consider for example:

$$\begin{array}{rrcr}
  & 10 & < & 20 \\
- & 6 & <  & 18 \\ \hline
  & 4 & <  & 2 & \color{red}{\text{OOPS}}
\end{array}$$

What you *can* do is add them:

$$\begin{array}{rccc}
  & a & < & b \\
+ & c & <  & d \\ \hline
  & a+c & <  & b+d 
\end{array}$$

To find the corresponding rule for subtraction, let's multiply the second inequality by $-1$, which changes it from  $c<d$ to $-d<-c$.  Then we add:

$$\begin{array}{rccc}
  & a & < & b \\
+ & -d & <  & -c \\ \hline
  & a-d & <  & b-c 
\end{array}$$

This is the rule you were looking for:

> If  $a<b$ and $c<d$, you can conclude that $a-d < b-c$.

If we try this technique on the example at the top of this post, we get $10-18 < 20-6$, which is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can always add inequalities. Subtraction is just addition with a minus sign. When you take the negative of an inequality, you have to switch the direction of the inequality.

Go from there.